# How can I access the request body of a POST request from Flex?

Tags: html, apache-flex, http-post

I have an HTML page and it needs to send a POST request for another HTML page that's embedding a Flex application. How can I access the request body from that request in Flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used a GET request and attached the data to the URL. I know it's ugly, but couldn't find any other way...

Answer (score 1):

Even though you say that you are POSTING a request from one HTML page to another; that is not actual what happens.  The POST rewuest is sent to a server.  That server may then process the request somehow and spit out a new HTML page.  But, you cannot POST from one HTML page to another.

Since Flex is a client side technology, you cannot use a POST Request to pass data into it.  You also wouldn't be able to access the POST request from Javascript as a parallel.

So, you can have your server process the data, and prepare it to send back to your Flex app.  You could do this using FlashVars.  If you have a greater data set, then you could somehow save the data to the server, and load it into the Flex app using HTTPService, RemoteObject, or WebService.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **FlashVar** and **External Interface** to pass data from parent page to embeded Flex app 
Please take a look on [Communicating with the wrapper](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f17.html)

Hopes that Helps